# IOException and SocketException when Reading stream returned from WCF Service via Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, large-files, servicebus

We have created a download application which downloads large zip files(>200 MB) from a WCF service host which is residing on a remote machine. The client communicates to this WCF serivce via azure service bus using the **"nettcprelaybinding"**.

For downloading a zip file, WCF service creates a  stream an returns it. At client, we use this stream to write in a zip file.

But during reading this stream I randomly get **IOException** which says
**"An exception has been thrown when reading the stream."**.
When I closely look at the inner exception, I find **SocketException** (s) lined up.

**Following is the XML Stack Trace from WCF Trace Utility at Client:**

```
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An exception has been thrown when reading the stream.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at RPKDDM.ViewModel.SearchQueueViewModel.DownloadBackground(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]&amp; outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object o)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.IO.IOException: An exception has been thrown when reading the stream. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.HybridConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.HybridConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.MaxMessageSizeStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.TryEnsureBytes(Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.EnsureBytes(Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadText(XmlTextNode textNode, ValueHandleType type, Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadPartialBinaryText(Boolean withEndElement, Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadNode()
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.HybridConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.HybridConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.MaxMessageSizeStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.TryEnsureBytes(Int32 count)
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.EnsureBytes(Int32 count)
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count)
at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadText(XmlTextNode textNode, ValueHandleType type, Int32 length)
at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadPartialBinaryText(Boolean withEndElement, Int32 length)
at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadNode()
at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.MoveToContent()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.HybridConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.HybridConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.SingletonInputConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.MaxMessageSizeStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.TryEnsureBytes(Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.EnsureBytes(Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadText(XmlTextNode textNode, ValueHandleType type, Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadPartialBinaryText(Boolean withEndElement, Int32 length)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadNode()
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)</ExceptionString>
<DataItems>
<Data>
<Key>Microsoft.ServiceBus</Key>
<Value>Microsoft.ServiceBus</Value>
</Data>
</DataItems>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The read operation failed, see inner exception.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '22:59:58.0620000'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)</ExceptionString>
<DataItems>
<Data>
<Key>Microsoft.ServiceBus</Key>
<Value>Microsoft.ServiceBus</Value>
</Data>
</DataItems>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
```

**STREAM CONTRACT**

```
[MessageContract]

public class StreamFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public bool IsEmpty;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string QueueNumber;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream.Dispose();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code for reading the stream:**

```
    int bufferSize = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = streamInfo.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    int totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

    while (bytesRead > 0)
{
//WRITE BUFFER TO ZIP FILE
zipFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
zipFileStream.Flush();
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

//READ BYTES FROM SERVER STREAM
bytesRead = streamInfo.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

}
```

I am disposing this stream in finally block after the read process finishes.

**Client Binding:**

```
<netTcpRelayBinding>
        <binding name="default"
                 connectionMode="Hybrid"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="0"          
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 closeTimeout="01:00:00"
                 openTimeout="00:30:00"
                 sendTimeout="05:00:00"
                 receiveTimeout="05:00:00"
                 maxConnections="2500"
                 listenBacklog="200">


          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession enabled="false" ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpRelayBinding>
```

**Similar binding is present at server**
At service I have also enabled throttling with maximum values set.

**Service Behavior Configuration:**

```
<services>
      <!-- Application Service -->
      <service name="DDMService.DDMBaseService" behaviorConfiguration="ThrottleBehavior">
        <endpoint name="RelayEndpoint"
                  contract="IBaseService"
                  binding="netTcpRelayBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="default"
                  behaviorConfiguration="asyncBehavior"
                  address=""/>        
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ThrottleBehavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="asyncBehavior">
          <dispatcherSynchronization asynchronousSendEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

I am completely clueless why this is happening.
Is it because of some Service Bus error or known issue or Service Bus timeout?
For **Service Bus Quotas** I'm referring this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee732538.aspx

what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to set proper buffer size for reading the stream? or I need to set *maxBufferSize* and *maxBufferPoolSize*?

I have already tried setting *maxBufferSize* and *maxBufferPoolSize* to 2147483647.
But that does not help.

For **Large File Streaming** I'm referring this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

I am really fed up and cannot understand why this error occurs.
Please help.

**EDIT:**
If not able to help me with above, please tell me how can I resume my streaming from same point when IOException occurs? It would be of great help. Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: @JackWoodward Did not find a solution to this

Comment: not sure if this applies to you but it seems if you don't read from the stream for 10 - 20 seconds service bus will kill the connection

Answer (score 0):

You know that you get great file streaming capabilities from the Azure Blob storage, right ?

If the files are already zip files, I would look into that, because it would enable you to more or less remove your WCF layer.

If not, try looking into this [WCF Streaming large data (500MB / 1GB) on a self hosted service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479885/wcf-streaming-large-data-500mb-1gb-on-a-self-hosted-service)

Comment: we have kept our 'folders to download' on the server and zip them on ad hoc basis. Whenever a user tries to download a particular folder, the service zips that folder, creates a stream and returns to the client.