# Trouble grasping the Async Pattern using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, file-transfer

I am developing a WCF Service on which the server would be capable to make an async call to the client request for specific bytes from a file.

Callback Contract:

```
public interface IControlChannelCallback
    {
        [...]

        [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
        IAsyncResult BeginGetRemoteFile(string filename, byte[] buffer, int position, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

        int EndGetRemoteFile(IAsyncResult ar);
    }
```

Implementation:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginGetRemoteFile(string filename, byte[] buffer, int position, int count, AsyncCallback callback,
            object state)
        {
            var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(x =>
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    fileStream.Position = position;

                    return fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }, state);

            return task.ContinueWith(x => callback(task));
        }

        public int EndGetRemoteFile(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var task = (Task<int>) ar;

            return task.Result;
        }
```

StateObject:

```
public class ServiceStreamReaderStateObject
    {
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;

        public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

        public int TotalRead { get; set; }

        public ServiceStreamReaderStateObject()
        {
            Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        }
    }
```

Service Usage:

```
private void Download()
{
    var state = new ServiceStreamReaderStateObject();

    _client.Callback.BeginGetRemoteFile(@"F:\1313363989488.jpg", state.Buffer, 0,      state.Buffer.Length, RealCallback, state);
}

private void RealCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var state = (ServiceStreamReaderStateObject) ar.AsyncState;

            var totalRead = _client.Callback.EndGetRemoteFile(ar);
        }
```

Everything seems to be working, when I call the `EndGetRemoteFile` method it returns 1024, which is how many bytes should have been read, but the problem is that the buffer encapsulated on the state object `ServiceStreamReaderStateObject` is empty (full of zeros).

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, following by my logic the buffer should be filled with data, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch: Can you remove the "private" access modifier on the Buffer property of "ServiceStreamReaderStateObject"

```
public class ServiceStreamReaderStateObject
{
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;

    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }

    public int TotalRead { get; set; }

    public ServiceStreamReaderStateObject()
    {
        Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you need position and count as parameters? Are you attempting to stream the file in chunks?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to get the file in chunks, so I don't have problems with too much memory usage.

Comment: Got it. check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479885/wcf-streaming-large-data-500mb-1gb-on-a-self-hosted-service

Comment: Very interesting that WCF already supports what I am trying to do with minimal code, but the problem now is that I can't find a binding which supports, duplex AND streamed transfer.

Comment: If you are not restricted to HTTP, the NetTCP binding supports full duplex communication if you need it. Also if your service and client are both behind a firewall, "WSDualHttpBinding" might be an option as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx

Comment: netTcpBinding doesn't support Duplex with Streamed transfer at the same time. Will take a look at WsDualHttpBinding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39606/discussion-between-bruno-klein-and-abhijeet-patel)

Comment: WSDualHttpBinding works, but it doesn't have the `MaxBufferSize` property and because of this I am still getting the giant memory usage when transferring big files. Let's continue this discussion on chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39606/discussion-between-bruno-klein-and-abhijeet-patel