# Stream 100 gig file over WCF?

Tags: wcf

Can I stream 100 Gig file over WCF to an IIS WebService?  I am running into

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (2147483647) has
>   been exceeded. TO increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property.

The only problem with that advice is I think I have it set to the max value.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479885/wcf-streaming-large-data-500mb-1gb-on-a-self-hosted-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to be sure you are using `transferMode="Streamed"` (Buffered which is the default will give you `OutOfMemoryException`) and set `MaxReceivedMessageSize` to be very large it can hold a long.  The real gotcha is that when you do a `"Configure Service Reference"` sometimes it will remove `transferMode="Streamed"` and revert you back the default `Buffered`